# Unable to trim whitespaces for the output of xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, whitespace

I am creating an xpath but I am having whitespaces in the xpath output. I tried using normalize-space but it didn't work.

```
((//a[contains(@class,'product-name')])[3])[normalize-space()='Printed Dress']
```

```
<div class="product-container" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="left-block">
    <div class="product-image-container">
        <a class="product_img_link" href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&amp;controller=product" title="Printed Dress" itemprop="url">
<img class="replace-2x img-responsive" src="http://automationpractice.com/img/p/8/8-home_default.jpg" alt="Printed Dress" title="Printed Dress"  width="250" height="250" itemprop="image" />
           </a>
                                                    <div class="quick-view-wrapper-mobile">
      <a class="quick-view-mobile" href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&amp;controller=product" rel="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&amp;controller=product">
        <i class="icon-eye-open"></i>
            </a>
</div>
                        <a class="quick-view" href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&amp;controller=product" rel="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&amp;controller=product">
                            <span>Quick view</span>
                        </a>
                                                                            <div class="content_price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                                                                    <span itemprop="price" class="price product-price">
                                        $26.00                                  </span>
                                    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />


                                                            </div>
                                                                                            </div>


                </div>
```

I wanted the output to be as only "Printed Dress" but i get the output as

```
                            Printed Dress
```

Answer (score 0):

`normalize-space` is a xpath function all it will do is trim the white spaces while evaluating the xpath but not the output.

You have to trim the output using the language specific method. Eg: if you are using python you can use `outPut.strip()`.

Comment: Btw, which language bindings you are using?

Comment: I am using Java

Comment: try using combination of `strip()`, `trim()`  and `replace()`.